# TabLayout and viewPager overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tabLayout and viewPager2 for displaying fragments. There is recyclerview in a fragment. It's working great but recyclerview overlapping some layout items. I tried to display viewpager under profile photo but constraintLayout becomes full width and height and then i can't show recyclerview correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.ProfileFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:title="@string/profile" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/coverPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/myToolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="29dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/coverPhoto"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/iconChange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_orange"
        app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_round_camera"
            app:tint="@color/white" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_photo"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/viewPager" />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.PersonalProductFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/personalProductsRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="25dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 </layout>
```